# Filtering XSLT Template By List of IDs

Tags: xml, xslt

Im picking up a legacy xslt file that needs to be updated and ive never coded in xsl before. I've tried a number of ways to achieve this, but can't get correct results. I have an xslt that generates a csv file. Before the csv file is saved, im trying to filter out the Allocations template if an ID != 3 or 7.

I've tried this and every possible iteration:
`<xsl:apply-templates select="Allocations/Allocation[ID != 3 and 7]" mode="FieldMap"/>`

This is what I currently have:

````
<xsl:param name="filterType" select="'3,7'"/>
<xsl:variable name="filter" select="concat(',', $filterType, ',')"/>
<xsl:template match="/Trade">

<xsl:variable name="Allocations">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="Allocations[contains($filter, concat(',', Allocations/Allocation/ID, ','))]" mode="FieldMap"/>
</xsl:variable>```


Any guidance would be greatly appreciated
````

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: "I've tried this and every possible iteration". You can't get code working by trial and error. You're clearly guessing, and you'd have to be very lucky to guess right. You need to read some tutorials or reference books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
select="Allocations/Allocation[ID != '3' and ID != '7']" mode="FieldMap"/>
```

**XSLT 2.0  and later**

```
select="Allocations/Allocation[not(ID=('3','7'))]" mode="FieldMap"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Didnt even realize I was working with 1.0. Worked. Apperciate the help